# Create something like SQL Trigger in Doctrine / Symfony 3

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a little problem and I can't solve it. 
I have a controller, which accept 4 variables using AJAX and I need to insert data in first table and then get ID value from first table and insert it to 2 with 2 additional parameters.
So, my app structure is:

1) Keywords Table with fields keywordId, KeywordVal and Page ID (getted from AJAX)

2) Translations table with fields keywordID (get from Keywords.keywordId), langCode and translation (AJAX)

3) Controller which get data from ajax, proceed it and insert into table.

So, my question is next: how can I configure my EventListener? This listener must be run after flush() method and insret data into Translations table.

Answer (score 1):

Why not you create it all in the controller, because to do all in a EventListener you must in some way to pass the values to the listener.

If you do it in your controller yo can to persist first the first entity with the needed parameters and in after persist the second entity related to de previusly created entity.

Something like:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$keyword = new Keyword($param1, $param2);
$em->persist($keyword);
$keywordTranslation = new KeywordTranslation($keyword, $param3, $param4);
$em->persist($keywordTranslation);
$em->flush();
```

I think is so much easy to do

Comment: Intersting solution, will try it if will no have success with Listeners :) Tnx

Answer (score 1):

<strike>What you seem to need is a Doctrine Listener. Here is the [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#implementing-event-listeners) to create a Doctrine listener. You might want to use the preFlush event in my opinion. Be careful, this event is fired for every flush, not only for Keywords, so you've got to check first it is a Keyword before creating Translations.</strike>

**EDIT:** Nevermind, just noticed this does not answer to your question. However, I feel your model could be improved, because you should not have to flush several times to insert a single set of data. Theoretically, you should have a **OneToMany** relationship between Keywords and Translations, and Doctrine would manage alone to link the two entities with their id at insertion.